# Deploying to AWS lambda hits size limit and packages (such as numpy) are not compatible

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, firebase-admin

I have a relatively small script where I use the following dependencies:

```
firebase-admin
pandas
```

Nevertheless, when you install these dependencies you get over 60 additional dependencies installed as well, such as `numpy`, `scikit`, `google_cloud` etc.

I encountered many problems during deployment, of which the following were the most striking:

1. You quickly hit the size limit of 250MB. numpy alone is approx 100mb.
2. Some packages with compiled libraries are not compatible, e.g. `numpy`, so you need to unwheel them (see [link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-python-package-compatible/)).

I have spent now maybe two days trying to get around these problems. However, I did not manage to succeed to run my small script at all.

I am therefore wondering:

- Is AWS lambda at all suitable for my use case given the difficulties in deploying? If it is so hard to deploy a simple script with the dependencies listed above?
- What are other good practices to overcome the dependency installation? Is it possible to split up the dependencies from the actual functions?
- What are other better (more simple) ways to deploy to Lambda? In particular, I find it cumbersome to zip every time all my functions and site-packages in order to just to do a *small update*.

---

Note on the latter: I have tried also the following solutions:

- **zappa**: Following this [tutorial](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-create-a-serverless-service-in-15-minutes-b63af8c892e5), I tried deploying it using zappa. After encountering and somehow resolving the size limit problem, I had another problem which is that my small script did not had an app function in the format myservice.app. After googling I found that zappa was designed for WSGI apps.
- **python-lambda**: I also tried this other often recommended alternative. However, I was unable to call the command `lambda init` after installation. See my question on that issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54114519/python-lambda-lambda-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-op).
- **using aws sam and layers**. I followed the `README.me` after installing `aws-sam-cli` and followed all the steps. This resulted that I uploaded a new package on S3, which I used to create a new layer. Nevertheless, I kept receiving the error "numpy not found" despite that I put `numpy` in my requirements.txt and properly build the site packages (as it was in my SamApp visible).

Comment: You can resolve this issue consdering Lambda Layers for all your dependencies. Lambda Layers allow you share code with all your Lambda runtime. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html

Comment: So call a zip file of 100-200mb on startup?

Comment: You wouldn’t need to call it any differently than you would without using lambda layers. Layers will be make it enable for your lambda at the time of invocation and you would import dependencies normally as you do in python. Make sure you have read through the doc to ensure layers are configured properly.

Comment: I will try but it seems very cumbersome. How come there is no magic "aws deploy" button that does everything?

Comment: Use it and you will love it. Better than deploy button ;)

Comment: After the upload, can you delete the s3 file?

Comment: Tips on packaging numpy/pandas as layers? I downloaded no-binary packages, zipped it, but it seems it does not find it.

Comment: I've not used layers in Python runtime but I've been using it in Node.js. Essentially idea is the same. f you can be specific about the issues you are having then I can try help you. This [blog](https://blog.skbali.com/2018/11/aws-lambda-layer-example-in-python/) appears to be a quick guide for setting up layers for Python runtime.

Comment: Thanks for that. Tried everything also your link and even aws sam cli but still same error. This is not normal how complicated it is.

Comment: what does your zip folder structure look like?

Comment: I switched to Cloud Functions. Had everything up and running in 30 min, whereas spent 2 days on figuring out Aws lamda. See also my other comment.

Comment: I'm glad your issue has been resolved :)

Comment: I am using Zappa in a non-wsgi sense and I am finding it quite useful. Interesting about google functions though. My only worry would be [cost](https://medium.com/@manus.can/serverless-platform-comparison-google-cloud-function-vs-aws-lambda-8e060bcc93b4) which would only be a problem at really large scales I imagine.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy to lambda & surrounding services using serverless framework. I use serverless framework with the serverless-python-requirements plugin which will compile and bundle any needed python requirements. Under the hood it translates into a cloudformation template and deploys your function(s) and dependent resources as a stack into AWS.

Comment: Tried it but the file size exceeded 250mb for a small package. I switched to Google Cloud Functions with Firebase. Honestly, I had a code up and running within 30 minutes, while I spent 2 full working days trying to figure out aws lambda. I honestly dont understand why people use Amazon/Aws when you have everything much better and cleaner done on Cloud Functions. Tomorrow I buy a Google Cloud t-shirt.